# Help with the coordinate space of a Rectangle

Tags: actionscript-3, coordinates

If I have a simple class that has a rectangle:

```
package 
{

import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;

public class Spot extends Sprite
{
    private var __rect:Rectangle;

    public function  Spot()
    {
        init();
    }

    private function init():void
    {
        __rect = this.getRect(this);

    }

    public function get rect():Rectangle{
            return __rect;
    }

}

}
```

And I animate an instance of this class on the stage and try to trace it's coordinates:

```
package 
{

import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.geom.Point;

public class RectangleTest extends Sprite
{
    public var spot:Spot = new Spot();
    public function  RectangleTest()
    {
        init();
    }

    private function init():void
    {
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, dynamicSpotTrace, false, 0, true);      
    }

    private function dynamicSpotTrace(e:Event):void
    {
        trace(spot.rect.x, spot.rect.y, spot.rect.width, spot.rect.height);
    }

}

}
```

The output traces:

```
0 0 65 65
```

Over and over (since the Spot has a registration point of 0,0)...how can I rewrite this so I can get the new coordinates of the Spot instance at every frame (since the spot is actually moving across the screen??)

Comment: Which element are you actually targeting in your animation? What I mean is, if you're moving rect and not spot, spot is simply moving with rect and not truly moving itself.

Comment: Oh yes, I am moving the Spot...I hope the rect would track with the spot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With taskinoor's answer in mind, you can do it a lot easier.

```
private function dynamicSpotTrace(e:Event):void
{
    var rect:Rectangle = spot.getRect(stage);
    trace(rect);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The parameter to `getRect` is the `targetCoordinateSpace`, that is in which display object's coordinate space the rectangle will be represented. So I guess instead of `this` you need to pass a reference to the display object on which coordinate system you want to get the rectangle, that is the parent display object of `Spot`. Passing `this` means `Spot` will return rectangle in it's own local coordinate system which always have (0, 0) as the origin. If you want the result in `RectangleTest` coordinate system then you can pass a reference of that in `Spot` constructor and use that as a parameter of `getRect`.

Note: I really have not tested this myself, but this is what I understand after reading the manual.